# how to locate which startup scripts executes riak startup

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, startup, riak

I have a 64bit ubuntu server in a virtual machine, and I have some scripts running at startup, and I can't seam to locate in which file do we have the riak startup setup.

I searched a lot of files mainly under /etc and none of them contained the startup sequence.

I checked rc.local is empty.

I am talking about this startup sequence: http://screencast.com/t/OtejvY9Ez

Comment: Did you look in `/etc/init.d`?

Comment: there is a file /etc/init.d/riak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an `/etc/init.d/riak` file. That is the most likely culprit.

Comment: how to remove it, or edit the statup sequence (host, params to riak) ?

Comment: This is not a discussion forum, and this is a separate question, so please post it as a proper qustion.

Comment: "how to remove it, or edit the statup sequence (host, params to riak) ?" - by reading debian docs and riak docs would be the best way.

Comment: I couldn't find the answer on Google, I'm also wondering how to stop it.